# Retrieving a list of GORM persistent properties for a domain

Tags: grails, grails-orm

What's the best/easiest way to get a list of the persistent properties associated with a given GORM domain object?  I can get the list of all properties, but this list contains non-persistent fields such as `class` and `constraints`.

Currently I'm using this and filtering out the list of `nonPersistent` properties using a list I created:

```
    def nonPersistent = ["log", "class", "constraints", "properties", "errors", "mapping", "metaClass"]
    def newMap = [:]
    domainObject.getProperties().each { property ->
        if (!nonPersistent.contains(property.key)) {
            newMap.put property.key, property.value
        }
    }
```

There seems like there must be a better way of getting just the persistent properties.

Comment: To be a bit more explicit, persistentProperties only provides property names, not values.  getProperties() is still necessary if you need both keys and values of properties. Confusing since Gorm is not  consistent with its use of the term 'property'

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try this:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClass
...
def d = new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(YourDomain.class)
d.persistentProperties
```

Here's a link to the Grails API for [GrailsDomainClass](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.2.x/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsDomainClass.html) (it's a link to an older version; I couldn't find a newer one after some quick searches). It's got a `getPersistentProperties()` (used in the code snippet above). You can traverse the API documentation to see what other methods might be useful to you.

If you want an example, do a `grails install-templates` and then look at `src/templates/scaffolding/create.gsp`. There's a block in there where it iterates over the persistent domain properties.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I had tried that but I get the following exception: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: persistentProperties for class: com.infinitecampus.standards.LLevel`.  The LLevel object is a GORM object I created with new LLevel().  Perhaps I'm doing something else wrong?

Comment: That's strange. What happens if you cast it to a GrailsDomainClass, e.g. `((GrailsDomainClass)domainObject).persistentProperties`?

Comment: Tried it, here's what happened:  `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'Name' with class 'com.infinitecampus.standards.LLevel' to class 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsDomainClass'`

Comment: After doing some more reading I updated my example. Give it a try.

Answer (score 13):

Now (strarting Grails 2.x) you don't even have to instantiate `new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(...)` and avoid unnecessary code executions. All domain class objects have injected property `domainClass`:

```
def domainObject = new YourDomain()
domainObject.domainClass.persistentProperties
```

Or, if you haven't domain class object, you can get `DefaultGrailsDomainClass` from application context by domain class name - each domain class has a DefaultGrailsDomainClass registered as a Spring bean. So you can use, for example, `Holders` (assuming your domain class name is 'Foo'):

```
def defaultGrailsDomainClass = Holders.applicationContext.getBean("FooDomainClass")
defaultGrailsDomainClass.persistentProperties
```

Comment: I like this as a convenience on top of Rob's answer. However, the correct property name is actually persistentProperties, not persistedProperties.

Answer (score 9):

As of `grails 3.3.0`

> All code that uses the `GrailsDomainClass` or `GrailsDomainClassProperty` classes should be re-written to use the mapping context api.
>
> To get started, inject the `grailsDomainClassMappingContext` bean. See the api documentation for more information on the `MappingContext`, `PersistentEntity` (GrailsDomainClass), and `PersistentProperty`(GrailsDomainClassProperty)

For example:

```
class MyService {
    def grailsDomainClassMappingContext //inject

    def accessDomainProperties(Class clazz) {
        PersistentEntity entityClass = grailsDomainClassMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(clazz.name)
        List<PersistentProperty> persistentPropertyList = entityClass.persistentProperties
        persistentPropertyList.each { property ->
            println property.name
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This helped me, but is there a way to find out current property is allowed to be nullable or not? I have given constraint in the domain. I tried but didn't get proper values for constraint and its value. I want to get constraint and it value

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I think you to check nullable using `persistentProperty.isNullable()` method. But you can't access value unless it's `static propertey` or a initiated under object. To access static property value you can use `GrailsClassUtils.getStaticPropertyValue(clazz,prop)`

Comment: above returns non transient objects to retun transient under grails 3.2+ `def d = new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(clazz)
        List properties=d.persistentProperties.transients.sort().unique().flatten()` with above answer gets all

Comment: `DefaultGrailsDomainClass` class is deprecated, so I won't recommend using that.

Comment: @charu-jain `persistentProperty.getAssociations()` returns a list of the associations for this entity. This is typically a subset of the list returned by `getPersistentProperties()`. You can further check `Association.owningSide` to determine which side of the relation you are in.

Comment: Thanks @MamunSardar for this great answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**From your domain** it's possible to get the persistent properties calling first the static method [`getGormPersistentEntity()`](https://gorm.grails.org/latest/api/org/grails/datastore/gorm/GormEntity.html#getGormPersistentEntity()):

```
def newMap = [:]
YourDomain.gormPersistentEntity.persistentProperties.each { property ->
    newMap.put("$property.name", domainObject."$property.name")
}
```

---

Another alternative is to use [`HibernateMappingContext`](https://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/api/org/grails/orm/hibernate/cfg/HibernateMappingContext.html):

Through *grailsApplication*

```
// Inject grailsApplication   
grailsApplication.mappingContext.getPersistentEntity(YourDomain.class.name).persistentProperties
```

or *grailsDomainClassMappingContext*

```
// Inject grailsDomainClassMappingContext 
grailsDomainClassMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(YourDomain.class.name).persistentProperties
```