# Grails / Groovy - Domain Object - Map of its Properties

Tags: reflection, grails, groovy, dns, metaprogramming

How can I get a map of the key/values of only the user-defined properties on one of my domain objects?

Problem is if I do this myself, I get my properties plus class, metaClass, constraints, closures, etc...

I assume Grails can do this fairly easily because it is done at some level in the scaffold code right? How can I do this myself?

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555150/gorm-persistent-properties

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to suggest. You have to be careful with transient properties obviously.

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```
class Person{
    String name
    String address
}

def filtered = ['class', 'active', 'metaClass']

def alex = new Person(name:'alex', address:'my home')

def props = alex.properties.collect{it}.findAll{!filtered.contains(it.key)}

props.each{
    println it
}
```

It also works if you use `alex.metaClass.surname = 'such'`. This property will be displayed in the each loop

Comment: This works for normal groovy classes, but is not so neat for grails domain objects as grails domain objects have extra magic wrapped around them that will get printed as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I just ran across this requirement and found [another solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8801/returning-groovy-class-fields-as-a-map) that is worth answering here for others who come across this thread. I have put together an example based on that thread:

**Sample Bean**

```
class SampleBean {

    long id
    private String firstName
    String lastName
    def email

    Map asMap() {
        this.class.declaredFields.findAll { !it.synthetic }.collectEntries {
            [ (it.name):this."$it.name" ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
class Test {

    static main(args) {
        // test bean properties
        SampleBean sb = new SampleBean(1,'john','doe','jd@gmail.com')

        println sb.asMap()
    }

}
```

The `SampleBean` I put a variety of fields to show that it works, this is the output of the println:

```
[id:1, firstName:john, lastName:doe, email:jd@gmail.com]
```

Comment: This works for normal groovy classes, but is not so neat for grails domain objects as grails domain objects have extra magic wrapped around them that will get printed as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use .properties on a domain object to get map of the fields in grails , tested in grails 2.1

```
class Person{
String firstName
String lastName

} 
def person=new Person()
person.firstName="spider"
person.lastName="man"
def personMap=person.properties
```

Comment: The question asks about only returning *user-defined* properties - `person.properties` will return more than just the user-defined properties.

Answer (score 0):

### Grails Domain Objects

You can use Grails Gorm's [`getPersistentProperties()`](https://gorm.grails.org/latest/api/org/grails/datastore/mapping/model/PersistentEntity.html#getPersistentProperties()), if you are not including any transient properties on your map.

```
def domainProperties = [:]

YourDomain.gormPersistentEntity.persistentProperties.each { prop ->
    domainProperties.put(prop.name, yourDomainObject."$prop.name")
}
```

**If you want to include transient properties**, just write another loop on the property `transients`:

```
YourDomain.transients.each { propName ->
    domainProperties.put(propName, yourDomainObject."$propName")
}
```

Read [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75687179/15016163) for some more detail on `persistentProperties`.

---

### Groovy Objects

For simple POGOs, as others pointed out in their answers, the following does the job:

```
def excludes = ['class']
def domainProperties = yourPogo.properties.findAll { it.key !in excludes }
```

or

```
Map map = [:]
yourPogo.class.declaredFields.each {
   if (!it.synthetic) map.put(it.name, yourPogo."$it.name")
}
```

---

You can get the best alternative that suits your needs and implement it on a method in a `trait` to be inherited or create a utility method that accepts the object as argument.