# How do I get declared properties in Grails domain objects?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to convert Grails domain objects to Map. I have a code that do it for POGOs using Apache Commons BeanUtils' [`PropertyUtils.describe`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#describe(java.lang.Object)). However, using the same code on domain objects just doesn't work because of all the stuff added by the Grails framework. I want to be able to convert any object to a Map with only the declared fields just like how Grails converts domain objects to JSON. What features can help me achieve this?

Comment: Does `domainObject.domainClass.persistedProperties` get you closer?

Comment: It could, but I'm looking for a more general solution that works on (almost) any Groovy object in the application. Something like bypassing all the features added by Groovy, and Grails.

Comment: Not sure you can, due to the different way properties are handled...  The groovy way (afair) is do do something like `domainObject.class.declaredFields.findAll { !it.synthetic }.name` but I'm not sure how that would work with Grails domain classes or dynamically added properties

Comment: I'll test that. Is there a way to create a temporary domain class just for testing? Will something like `class MyClass implements GrailsDomainClass` do? I want to create a Spec that doesn't get affected when any of my actual domain classes changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this inside your domain class:

```
    public Map asMap() {
        this.class.declaredFields.findAll { !it.synthetic }.collectEntries {
          [ (it.name):this."$it.name" ]
        }
    }
```

There are other questions about the same problem, did you try this? [Grails / Groovy - Domain Object - Map of its Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343264/grails-groovy-domain-object-map-of-its-properties)