# Getting bean properties names in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, properties, dns, taglib

I'm trying to write a tag, which will render my bean properties and corresponding values. I want the default behaviour be to render all properties from the bean. So I need somehow get all property names from passed bean.

I figured that I could use `properties` map, but despite bean properties, there are also other things and I'd have to manage it by hand which may be error prone.

I also thought of using `DefaultGrailsDomainClass` which is handy for domain classes, but is useless for command objects.

Have you ever done something similar and came up with something useful?

Comment: Have you looked at the bean-fields plugin? It sounds like you might be trying to re-implement some of it's functionality

Comment: Yes I did. One thing that differs what I'm trying to do from bean-fields is that I want to render all properties at once, just by passing object to tag. In bean-fields, you have to explicitly tell which properties to render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555150/gorm-persistent-properties), there are also `persistentProperties`. But I believe you need [`GrailsDomainClass.properties`](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsDomainClass.html#getProperties%28%29) - don't confuse with Groovy `properties`, the former are for domain **class**.

For rendering, [`GrailsDomainClassProperty.naturalName`](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsDomainClassProperty.html#getNaturalName%28%29) will also be useful.

Comment: So for now I'm going to narrow functionality and allow only bean rendering and use GrailsDomainClass. Maybe some time I'll try to make it available for command objects.

Comment: Command is not a bean BTW - I learned this lately. Maybe you can just use `Class.declaredFields/declaredMethods` for them.

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar thing by using `properties`, no problem. My code was:

```
value.properties.entrySet().each { Map.Entry it ->
    println "$it.key = $it.value"  
}
```

Comment: I'm aware it is possible, but I in such scenario I have to omit by hand such entries like metaClass, transients, class and few more. Also, if there are relationships involved, I have to manage it by hand.

Comment: Oh, I got it. At my case it wasn't required