# Grails 4 replacement for DefaultGrailsDomainClass?

Tags: grails

I'm recreating a working Grails 2.2.5 application in Grails 4 in order to get to know the new version (with the view to migrating all 2.2.x apps over in due course). So far I've only moved a handful of Groovy classes from the src directory over, but I'm running into a compile problem with a class which is apparently no longer present in Grails 4, org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClass. I use this to iterate through the persistent properties of a domain class (with `persistentProperties`). How would I do this in Grails 4? I.e., get all the persistent properties of a domain class?

Comment: This was deprecated in grails 3.3.x (maybe earlier?).  See http://docs.grails.org/3.3.2/guide/upgrading.html for info on the upgrade path.  I don't have a working example for grails 4 yet, but in case no one else chimes in with an actual answer, that may at least get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: No mention of it in the upgrade guide, unfortunately. I believe the answer may be to use PersistentEntity, and I'm looking for some good examples online.

Comment: The grails 3 upgrade guide does reference it, at least.  Search the link above for "Grails Domain Class API Deprecated".  There are some good links, though not necessarily examples.  But yes, PersistentEntity, PersistenProperty, and an injected grailsDomainClassMappingContext are the way to go.

Comment: I am using this in a straight Groovy class in the /src directory, so I imagine I can't inject the grailsDomainClassMappingContext there, can I?

Comment: You should be able to wire beans into a groovy class. Take a look at scaffolding for some examples of using persistentProperties https://github.com/grails/scaffolding/blob/master/core/src/main/groovy/org/grails/scaffolding/model/property/DomainPropertyImpl.groovy

Answer (score 3):

`DefaultGrailsDomainClass` is indeed deprecated since [Grails 3.3.2](http://docs.grails.org/3.3.2/guide/upgrading.html) in favor of the mapping context API. Fortunately, it is quite straightforward to replace the deprecated implementation.

Inject the `grailsDomainClassMappingContext` bean in your service or controller:

```
def grailsDomainClassMappingContext
```

then get the persistent entity by providing its name:

```
def entity = grailsDomainClassMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(domainObjName)
```

where `domainObjName` is a string and `entity` is an instance of [`org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.PersistentEntity`](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/api/org/grails/datastore/mapping/model/PersistentEntity.html). You can also get a specific property by using:

```
def property = entity.getPropertyByName(propertyName)
```

where `propertyName` is a string and `property` is an instance of [`org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.PersistentProperty`](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/api/org/grails/datastore/mapping/model/PersistentProperty.html).

The interfaces `PersistentEntity` and `PersistentProperty` offer a variety of useful methods to cover many uses.

Answer (score 0):

Read my answer on [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75687179/15016163):

> #### 1. `YourDomain.gormPersistentEntity.persistentProperties`
>
> #### 2. Inject grailsApplication
>
> ```
> grailsApplication.mappingContext.getPersistentEntity(YourDomain.class.name).persistentProperties
> ```
>
> #### 3. Inject grailsDomainClassMappingContext
>
> ```
> grailsDomainClassMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(YourDomain.class.name).persistentProperties
> ```